# Handling very small numbers in ratio and how to keep exponential value

Tags: r, performance, exponential

I am currently using R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15) with R Studio.

I need to calculate ratio of two values. And I have problems with some case :

- The numerator can be very small value : exp(-2408.9) that R approximate with 0.
- The denominator also :  exp(-2405) is calculated as 0 is R.

When the ratio is computed, I get a NaN (because of 0/0).

**First solution** :

I use the *Brobdingnag* library that allows to keep number as exponentiel, and finally obtain that the ratio actually is : exp(-3.8987) = 0.02026725

But, checking at the performance of my code with the library *profvis*, I can see that despite the fact that the Brobdingnag library is very useful in my case, it cost me a lot in term of performance. And I cannot keep this solution, because I have to do a lot of simulations of my algorithm.

**Questions for an other solution :**

Have you heard about an other library to deal with very small (or large) values ?

I would like to keep my numerator and denominator in an exponential expression until the division is made, but I have no idea of how to do it. Because of course, my numerator and denominator are vectors, that I divide once they are both calculated. (I can not obtain denominator without the numerator vector)
Is there a way to "force" R to keep a value as exp instead of integer (and 0...) ?

Thank you in advance for any help.

EDIT :

Here is the ratio I have to calculate :

https://ibb.co/dFHx4z

I am not sure I can use the trick : exp(x)/exp(y) = exp(x-y) because I have a sum into the denom. 
That's why I need the exp formula until I do the ratio... 
Value inside the exp are very large negative number, and exp of these numbers make 0. Plus, I tried to transform numerator as log, so I can have log of firt past + second part (without exp) but sometimes, first part of numerator (1/sqrt...) is to small and log of it returns Inf..

I think there is a way, but I can' find it.

Thanks for all the answers btw!

EDIT 2 :

```
####### Fonction that calculate the density (with brobdingnag package) :

density <- function(nc,yc,X,beta,sig,k){

    # n_c is a vector of integer 
    # y_c is a vector of numeric 
    # X is a matrix 
    # beta is a vector of numeric 
    # sigma is a value

res<-as.brob((1/(2*pi*sig[k])))^(nc/2)*exp(as.brob(-(1/(2*sig[k]))*t(yc-(X %*% beta[,k])) %*% (yc-(X %*% beta[,k]))))
return(res)
}

####### Code for calculation of the ratio :

# n_c[c] : num [1] 340
# y_c[c] : num [1:340] 1.279 0.777 1.069 0.864 1.56 ...
# X[c] : num [1:340, 1:11] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ... (matrix of 0 and 1)
# beta : num [1:11, 1:2] 1.542 -0.226 -0.145 -0.438 -0.201 ...
# sigma : num [1:2] 21.694381  4.267277
# lambda : num [1] 0.5

# Numerator :

num_tau<-sapply(1:100,function(c){
        sapply(1:4,function(k){
            lambda[k]*density(n_c[c], y_c[c],X[c],beta,sigma,k)
        })
    })

# Denominator :

denom_tau<-list()
for (c in 1:100){
    val<-0
    for (k in 1:4){
        val<-val+num_tau[k,c][[1]]
    }
denom_tau[[c]]<-val
}

# Ratio :
for (l in 1:4){
    for (c in 1:100){
        tau[l,c]<-as.numeric(num_tau[l,c][[1]]/denom_tau[[c]])
    }
}
```

Comment: How about taking the log of both values, then the difference and then again the exponential?

Comment: I have a gaussian density to calculate (see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) into the ratio and it is the value into the exponential that is very small. And without brobdingnag, it gives me a 0 for this value that I have to multiply with an other term. If I take the log, it gives me -Inf. And then, starts the problem....

Comment: @FBT I believe Kath isn't saying take the log after you have already computed the exp part. They're saying if you do the math you'll see that exp(a)/exp(b) = exp(a-b). Use that to jump part the parts that are causing you problems.

Comment: I edited my question with more details on the formula I have to implement. Thank you for all the answers. @Dason

Comment: @FBT Your code can not be run. Can you edit it so that we could copy, paste and run it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @minem suggested, you can use the **Rmpfr** package. Here's one way to apply it to your case.

First move the multipliers inside the exponential of the numerator, using the fact that a*exp(b) = exp(b + log(a)). Then re-write your `density` function to compute the log numerator:

```
log_numerator <- function(nc, yc, X, beta, sig, k, lambda){
  v <- yc - X %*% beta[,k]
  res <- -sum(v*v)/(2*sig[k]) - (nc/2)*log(2*pi*sig[k]) + log(lambda[k])
  drop(res)
}
```

Note that `lambda` is now passed to this function. Also note that we can compute the dot product of the vector Y - X*beta more efficiently, as shown.

Now we can generate some data. Here I fix c and just have k = 1:2.

```
set.seed(1)
n_c <- 340
y_c <- rnorm(340)
dat <- data.frame(fac = sample(letters[1:11], 340, replace = TRUE)
X_c <- model.matrix(~ fac, data = dat)
beta <- matrix(runif(22, -10, 10), 11, 2)
sigma <- c(21.694381,  4.267277)
lambda <- c(0.5, 0.5)
```

Using your density function we have

```
x1 <- lambda[1] *density(n_c, y_c,X_c,beta,sigma,1)
y1 <- lambda[2] *density(n_c, y_c,X_c,beta,sigma,2)
x1
# [1] +exp(-1738.4)
y1
# [1] +exp(-1838.7)
as.numeric(y1/sum(x1, y1))
# [1] 2.780805e-44
```

Using the log-numerator function we have

```
p <- 40
x <- mpfr(log_numerator(n_c, y_c,X_c,beta,sigma,1, lambda), p)
y <- mpfr(log_numerator(n_c, y_c,X_c,beta,sigma,2, lambda), p)
x
# 1 'mpfr' number of precision  40   bits 
# [1] -1738.379327798
y
# 1 'mpfr' number of precision  40   bits 
# [1] -1838.67033143
exp(y)/sum(exp(x), exp(y))
# 1 'mpfr' number of precision  53   bits 
# [1] 2.780805017186589e-44
```

So certainly `mpfr` can be used to produce equivalent results, but without better test code it's hard to check timings.

You could also improve efficiency by using more vectorization. E.g. we can vectorize `log_numerator` over k:

```
log_numerator2 <- function(nc, yc, X, beta, sig, lambda){
  M <- yc - X %*% beta
  res <- -colSums(M*M)/(2*sig) - (nc/2)*log(2*pi*sig) + log(lambda)
  drop(res)
}
z <- log_numerator2(n_c, y_c, X_c, beta, sigma, lambda)
z
# [1] -1738.379 -1838.670
```

Now suppose we have the log numerators in a c by k matrix, for illustration suppose all c have the same values as `z`,

```
log_num <- mpfr(matrix(z, byrow = TRUE, 3, 2), p)
```

you can compute the ratios as follows

```
num <- exp(log_num)
denom <- apply(num, 1, sum) # rowSums not implemented for mpfr
num/denom
# 'mpfrMatrix' of dim(.) =  (3, 2) of precision  53   bits 
#     [,1]              [,2]                 
# [1,] 1.000000000000000 2.780805017186589e-44
# [2,] 1.000000000000000 2.780805017186589e-44
# [3,] 1.000000000000000 2.780805017186589e-44
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this very helpful answer and explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If both values need to be exponent-ed before, then you can use formula:

e^x / e^y = e^(x-y)

Otherwise you can try `Rmpfr` package.

Example:

```
require(Rmpfr)
p = 40
x <- mpfr(-2408.9, p)
y <- mpfr(-2405, p)
exp(x)/exp(y)
# 1 'mpfr' number of precision  40   bits 
# [1] 0.02024191147598
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried with Rmpfr. But it doesn't match for my problem. I edited my post with more details on the formula I have to implement.

Comment: @FBT why it does not match? can you give exact code in your post?

Comment: Yes, I've just edited with the exact code. Thank you.